# How to use web service from the net

Tags: c#, web-services

I have Visual Studio 2010, using c# and I want to add this web service to my site:
http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx

I have added the web reference as "getip"
and my code is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getip.GeoIPService yourip = new getip.GeoIPService();
    Label4.Text = yourip.GetGeoIPContext().ToString();    

}
```

But when the site loads the only thing appearing in my label is "getip.GeoIP  "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use Web References anymore. Use "Add Service Reference" instead. Web References use the old "ASMX" technology. All new work should use the WCF technology, even if you're calling a .asmx web service.

Second, the service has returned you an object of the type `getip.GeoIP`. There's no doubt properties in that object. Try

```
getip.GeoIP geo = yourip.GetGeoIPContext();
```

And then type "geo." and see what Intellisense tells you is in there. Alternatively, stop after that line in the debugger, and look inside to see what you want to put into your label.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. I guess it works now, but unfortunately the site I got the web service from is down.... LOL!